# Rails Routes - How to make them case insensitive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Routes in Ruby on Rails are case sensitive. It seems someone brought this up before, and it has been labeled will not fix.

http://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/393-routes-are-case-sensitive

That strikes me as unfortunate, as I don't really see any upside on my own application for routes to be case sensitive, while on the downside it creates a potential for confusion and a general appearance of lack of polish in my opinion.

What's the best way to make my routes case insensitive?

I found this tip on a Google search:

```
map.connect "web_feeds/:action", :controller  => 'web_feeds', :action => /[a-z_]+/i
```

This is clever, but it still leaves the web_feeds portion of the url case sensitive.  I don't see any similar way around this, however, without entering in each possible combination of wEb_feEds manually, but that is obviously a horrible solution for any number of reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just has the same problem, and solved it using middleware - have a look here:

http://gehling.dk/2010/02/how-to-make-rails-routing-case-insensitive/

Note: This only applies for Rails 2.3+

- Carsten

Comment: The above solution did not work for Rails 3, but I've fixed that now.

Comment: I finally made this into a gem, so it's  lot easier to use: https://rubygems.org/gems/route_downcaser

Comment: This solution is problmatic if you have some assets/images name in Mixed Case.
For example, if you are already using an image from assets/images/ABc_xyZZ.png (Mixed Case), then after using this solution, it will try to locate an image at assets/images/abc_xyzz.png (Lower Case) and server will respond with 404 not found.

Comment: @NadeemYasin this is solved by using the exclusion initializer.  # config/initializers/route_downcaser.rb

RouteDowncaser.configuration do |config|
  config.redirect = true

  config.exclude_patterns = [
    /assets\//i,
    /fonts\//i,
    /some\/important\/path/i
  ]
end

Answer (score 12):

Routes in Rails are case sensitive because URLs are case sensitive. From the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html):

> URLs in general are case-sensitive
>   (with the exception of machine names).
>   There may be URLs, or parts of URLs,
>   where case doesn't matter, but
>   identifying these may not be easy.
>   Users should always consider that URLs
>   are case-sensitive.

Comment: Interesting, did not know that.

Comment: I think that if the Web had started out on Windows then it might not have turned out that way!

Comment: I appreciate the fact that there are times when it is important to be able to differentiate case (though frankly the only instances I can think of are corner cases), but for the ordinary usage, this is against user expectations.  Users expect stackoverflow.com/questions to be the same as stackoverflow.com/Questions, and indeed, this is the case.  And I'm not sure ordinary users are not going to be taking the advice of the W3C that they "should always consider that URLs are case sensitive" into consideration.

Comment: I think one should be lenient toward what humans enter but 301 redirect to the canonical version of the URL.

Comment: @lyle With the route_downcaser gem, you have the option to do a redirect if you want.

Answer (score 4):

Well you could try another approach. Make the case transform serverside and send everything to rails downcase.

I think you can achieve this with either mod_rewrite or mod_spelling.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is, may be not an elegant way, but yet workable is:
Use a before_filter in your application controller like this.

```
  before_filter :validate_case

  def validate_case
    if request.url != request.url.downcase
      redirect_301_permanent_to request.url.downcase
    end
  end

  def redirect_301_permanent_to(url)
     redirect_to url, :status=>:moved_permanently 
  end
```

As i already told that its not an elegant but yet workable, so no down votes please. :P

Comment: It's better to do it in Rack. In the application controller you have already passed by Rails' route dispatcher.

Answer (score 2):

just monkey-patch it to downcase by default. simple example:

```
module ActionController
  module Caching
    module Pages
      def cache_page(content = nil, options = nil)
        return unless perform_caching && caching_allowed

        path = case options
          when Hash
            url_for(options.merge(:only_path => true, :skip_relative_url_root => true, :format => params[:format]))
          when String
            options
          else
            request.path
        end

        path = path.downcase

        self.class.cache_page(content || response.body, path)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: As the W3C states, URL's are case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Though URLs are case-sensitive, if you want to make your routes case-insensitive, there is a dirty hack you can do.

In application_controller.rb put:

```
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError do |exception|
 redirect_to request.url.downcase
end
```

But don't actually do that. You create a redirect loop for any non-existant routes. You really should parse request.request_uri into its components, downcase them, and use them to generate the legit route that you redirect to. As I mentioned right off, this is a dirty hack. However, I think this is better than making your route map ugly and hackish.

Comment: You should check if it's already downcased, something like
if request.url != request.url.downcase
redirect_to request.url.downcase
else
# render 404 file
end

Answer (score 0):

(Posting this years later)

If you are looking only for specific routes to be case insensitive, like it was in my case, what I ended up doing is the following.

Say your route is

```
  get "items/:id" => "item#show"
```

This will resolve `/item/123` but not `/ITEM/123` nor `Item/123`.

You can use a segment constraint, treat `item` as a param, and add a default so your routes helpers don't need to specify it (hence remain what they would be with the original route above):

```
  get ":item/:id", constraints: { item: /item/i }, defaults: { item: "item" }  => "item#show"
```

If you have multiple routes under `/item`, you can generalise this concept with a scope:

```
scope ":item/", constraints: { item: /item/i }, defaults: { item: "item" } do
  get "/:id" => "item#show"
  delete "/:id" => "item#destroy"
end
```