# Rails URL case sensitive

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want my login URL to be case insensitive in my Rails application. e.g if the user types in 'User_Login' it should redirect to 'user_login'. I m using rails 3.1. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This might be useful..: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291907/rails-routes-how-to-make-them-case-insensitive

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem a long time ago. Have a look at my solution here:

http://gehling.dk/2010/02/how-to-make-rails-routing-case-insensitive/

/ Carsten

Comment: I finally made this into a gem, so it's  lot easier to use: https://rubygems.org/gems/route_downcaser

Comment: Nice gem, but it doesn't completly answer the question since in doesn't redirect to the lower case url

Comment: FWIW, the route_downcaser gem now supports redirection as well. It has done so for quite a while, but I just stumbled upon this question again.