# Rails routing not working for case sensitive URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

After generating Pages Controller with this command -

```
>rails g controller Pages Home About Contact
```

and un comment the line `match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'` at `routes.rb` File.

when I was accessing my URL like -

```
http://localhost:3000/pages/home
```

It throws error

> Unknown action
>
> The action 'home' could not be found for PagesController

However this was working if accessed like this -

```
http://localhost:3000/pages/Home
```

Small/Up case was my first thought so I installed `route_downcaser` as suggested [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827233/rails-url-case-sensitive)

Now the problem is both URLs are throwing same error -

```
http://localhost:3000/pages/home
http://localhost:3000/pages/Home
```

**ERROR**

> Unknown action
>
> The action 'home' could not be found for PagesController

Let me know how can I solve this error.

My project at Github - [Github URL](https://github.com/swapnesh/Add_twitter_bootstrap)

Using `Windows 7`

Rails version - `3.2.9`

**EDIT**

```
routes.rb file - 

Addbootstrap::Application.routes.draw do
  get "pages/Home"

  get "pages/About"

  get "pages/Contact"

  get "pages/Drop_Down"

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

Comment: can you include your whole routes file?

Comment: "rake routes" and see /pages/Home is present or not

Comment: @jvnill I added the file as requested

Comment: @SachinR It was working previously (but for Capital case in HOME instead of home) as I mentioned above

Comment: Post your PagesController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ruby you do not want to use upcased method names. Names starting with upcase letters are reserved for constants (classes/modules).

Aside from that, if you are using a gem that downcases your route from Home to home, and the method is named Home, then that is why it will fail. Make sure the method names are downcased.

---

In case anyone is going to point this out, I'll preempt. CapsCase method names are valid in ruby, they are just not conventional, and may be confusing. As such are considered a BadIdea. The only really special thing about CapsCase names is when they are assigned a value, ruby will raise warnings if you try to assign it again.

Comment: as suggested I changed Home to home in pages Controller and changed name to home.html.erb in views and its working..just a check will this be sufficient or else I need to modify somewhere else also +1.

Comment: Do i uninstall the downcase gem as It was not working the way I was expecting

Comment: It's going to be easiest to keep everything downcased, including your URLs. Do you need the Url to have CapsCase?

Comment: No i am just a beginner in Rails..so dont know rails is quite sensitive :)

Comment: you should also change your routes.  the last line in it is a serious security risk.  You are better off with using `get 'pages/home'` that having that line in your routes file.