# Case insensitive user names in Rails 3 routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I am trying to allow users to access their accounts by their user name, regardless of how they capitalize it in the URL. So http://example.com/Username would go to the same page as http://example.com/username.

I am fine with the any other part of the URL being case sensitive (I know that's the standard), but I don't see a need to force a user to get the case of their user name correct in the URL.

Can this be done by adding certain settings in the routes.rb file alone?

I thought this would be straightforward but apparently it isn't.

I found a seemingly simple question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291907/rails-routes-how-to-make-them-case-insensitive) but there's only [one answer that I think will help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2292837/839847) and it's too hacky (by the author's own admission)

Comment: Why is this a routing issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this isn't a routing issue and you can address it in your controller code:

```
User.where("lower(username) = lower(?)", params[:username]).first!
```

or

```
User.where("lower(username) = ?", params[:username].downcase).first!
```

or

```
User.find(:first, :conditions => [ "lower(username) = ?", params[:username].downcase ])
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't look closely enough at the error messages I was getting and just (stupidly and lazily) assumed the error was occurring in the routing. Comparing lowercased versions of the username does indeed work.

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine to handle this behaviour in the controller, not in the routes.

```
# config/routes.rb
match ':username' => 'users#show'

# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def show
  username = params[:username]
  user = User.find_by_username(username) || User.find_by_username(username.downcase) 
  # or something along these lines...
end
```

An even nicer solution might be to store some kind of *slug* identification for the user that is always downcased and ready to be used in URLs. You could have a look at the awesome [**friendly_id gem**](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks ... your answer is perfectly good, just not as fast as that of @john-nagle.